# Django sending email: Connection unexpectedly closed

Tags: django, python-3.x

Getting error "Connection unexpectedly closed" both through site and shell.

Code: Settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'username@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Hunter2'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Views.py:

```
   send_mail(
       'Test',
       'test',
       'example@hotmail.com',
       ['example@hotmail.com'],
       fail_silently=False,
       )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that your host is blocking that port. Your settings.py looks fine. I would refer to your hosting provider to ensure that they allow the use of that port.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I've since changed my host and it's working perfectly. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Great stuff! When in doubt it's probably the host ;)

Comment: Hey, I have similar problem. Do you mind telling what did you changed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, similar to what was answered before. It is your mail host service.

While deploying your app you might have not hidden your EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD. Making your password public, the host service might have disabled your account.

Reset your password over there, and make sure you hide it while deploying by using *gitignore* and *environ* or something else.

Answer (score 0):

My email host is 163, port use 587. After I changed 587 to 25. Email send fine.

```py
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.163.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

Thanks Daniel.